# Setting an array value in multi-dimensional arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem:

I have an array of arrays with unknown amount of subarrays so my array might look like this:

```
array('element1'=>array('subelement1'=>'value'
                        'subelement2'=>array(...),
      'element2'=>array('something'=>'this',
                        'subelement1'=>'awesome'));
```

Now I want to write a function that is able to replace a value by having it's path in the array, the first parameter is an array that defines the keys to search for. If I want to replace 'value' in the example with 'anothervalue', the function call should look like this:

```
replace_array(array('element1','subelement1'),'anothervalue');
```

It should also be able to replace all values on a given level by using null or another placeholder e.g.

```
replace_array(array(-1, 'subelement1'),'anothervalue');
```

should replace both 'value' and 'awesome'.

I tried to get it work by using a recursive function and references (one call searches the first array by using the first element in the path variable, and then it calls itself again with the subarray until it has found all occurences defined by the given path).

Is there a smart way to get it done? As my reference idea doesn't seem to work that good.

I can post the code I'm using atm later on.

Thank you.

Comment: I would use a recursive algorithm for this yes - as long as it wasn't going to recurse more than 100 levels :)

Comment: You forgot to put the original array in the function signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**: I updated my answer to also do `-1`

**edit**: As `-1` is valid for use as an array key, I think you shouldn't use that to mark "all" keys. Arrays themselves however cannot be used as an array key. So in stead of `-1` , I have chosen to use an array (`[]` or `array()`) to mark "all" keys.

```
function replace_array(&$original_array, $path, $new_value) {
    $cursor =& $original_array;
    if (!is_array($path))
        return;
    while($path) {
        $index = array_shift($path);
        if (!is_array($cursor) || (!is_array($index) && !isset($cursor[$index])))
            return;
        if (is_array($index)) {
            foreach($cursor as &$child)
                replace_array($child, $path, $new_value);
            return;
        } else {
            $cursor =& $cursor[$index];
        }
    }
    $cursor = $new_value;
    return;
}

// use like : replace_array($my_array, array("first key", array(), "third key"), "new value");
// or php5.4+ : replace_array($my_array, ["first key", [], "third key"], "new value");
```

Comment: BTW This function only recurses when hitting the "all" keys marker. So there is not much overhead in using it.

Answer (score 0):

The key in constructing this method lies in [passing the array by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). If you do that, the task becomes quite simple.

It is going to be a recursive method, so the questions to ask should be:

- Is this the last recursion?
- What key do I have to look for in this level?

[`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift) comes in handy here as you get the first level and at the same moment shorten the `$searchPath` properly for the next recursion.

```
function deepReplace($searchPath, $newValue, &$array) {
                                          // ^- reference
    //Is this the last recursion?
    if (count($searchPath) == 0) {
        $array = $newValue;
    }
    if (!is_array($array))
        return;

    //What key do I have to look for in this level?
    $lookFor = array_shift($searchPath);

    //To support all values on given level using NULL
    if ($lookFor === null) {
        foreach ($array as &$value) {
                        // ^- reference
            deepReplace($searchPath, $newValue, $value);
        }
    } elseif (array_key_exists($lookFor, $array)) {
        deepReplace($searchPath, $newValue, $array[$lookFor]);
    }
}
```

See it work [here](http://codepad.org/QujBVsfm) like

```
deepReplace(array(null, "subelement1"), "newValue", $data);
deepReplace(array("element1", "subelement1"), "newValue", $data);
```